# How to pass UserProfile model to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am trying to implement simple membership in my application. My problem is that I want to be able to display the data in the userprofile table for the current user but I dont know how to select it from the DB

I have tried this but I am getting an error:

```
    UserProfile UserP = new UserProfile();

        ViewBag.Message = User.Identity.Name;
        return View();

        UserP = (from r in up.UserName
                  where up.UserName == User.Identity.Name.ToString()
                  select r).ToList().FirstOrDefault();


        return View(UserP);
```

Here is the error:

```
            Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'MvcApplication5.Models.UserProfile'   C:\Users\user\Desktop\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\Controllers\HomeController.cs 31  32  MvcApplication5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right (your code is little bit broken, it has two returns, so I assume there is just two pieces of code), try this:

```
UserP = (from r in up
                  where up.UserName == User.Identity.Name.ToString()
                  select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just get rid of up.UserName in your query. ToList() is also not needed.

P.S. For the future:

I also suggest you adding another column called LoweredUserName and perform checking in the following way:

```
where up.LoweredUserName == User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToLower()
```

Comment: Hi Roman, Really grateful for the response, but in this case what is "up"? Usually it would refer to the DBContext am I correct? But when I tried to run ADO.Entity Model it created errors because of the duplicated classes so I dont know what "up" should be???
Sorry I didnt make it very clear

Comment: Could you please provide more code of your application? Thanks!

Comment: Sorrym I dont really have any code to give you yet. What I just really need to know is what DBContext do i use to access the UserProfile table data???

Comment: Actually, yes. You have to use DbContext. It should look like this:

var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserName == User.Identity.Name.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: What is "context" and "up" you have above? Just to state again I know how to access table data normally with the ADO.NET Model creator. But not with these Simple membership tables..
Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Ah, you don't even have context. Okay, if you know how to access table data normally, just look at my previous response to other topic. Just put your logic to ValidatePassword: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454888/custom-database-with-asp-net-membership-and-authorisation/20455544#20455544

PS I don't like SimpleMembership, it's easier to make your own table and perform custom validation.

Comment: Thanks Roman. Im beginning to think the same and I think I will create a custom login. But since ive spent so long on it, just out of interest id like to know how to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can access the UserProfile.

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var username = User.Identity.Name;
var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
return View(user);
```

For more on [customizing the UserProfile and accessing it read this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for the reply
I tried your code there but I recieved an error. Visual studio gave me this error:

An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.

Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\App_Data\aspnet-MvcApplication5-20131208163103.mdf' as database 'aspnet-MvcApplication5-20131208163103'

Comment: This error is not specific to the code.  EF is having troubles connecting to the database you have configured for SimpleMembership. Try this QA. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012839/cannot-attach-the-file-mdf-as-database]